# JPG to PNG using RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm trying to convert a fetched image from JPG to PNG using RMagick, resize it and then store it on S3:

```
thumb = Magick::Image.read("artist.jpg").first
thumb.write("artist.png")
thumb.crop_resized!(120, 120, Magick::CenterGravity)

AWS::S3::S3Object.store("image.png", thumb.to_blob, AWS_BUCKET, :content_type => 'image/png', :access => :public_read)
```

The image does get saved as a png but when I open it in Preview, document type still says "JPEG image". In fact, the image won't even open in Photoshop unless I change the extension back to ".jpg". Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the format:

```
thumb = Magick::Image.read("artist.jpg").first
thumb.format = "PNG"
thumb.write("artist.png")
thumb.crop_resized!(120, 120, Magick::CenterGravity)

AWS::S3::S3Object.store("image.png", thumb.to_blob, AWS_BUCKET, :content_type => 'image/png', :access => :public_read)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, doing `thumb.format = "PNG"` didn't work, however doing `thumb.format('png')` does work.  Most likely due to changes in the past few years.

```
thumb = Magick::Image.read("artist.jpg").first
thumb.format("png")
thumb.crop_resized!(120, 120, Magick::CenterGravity)
AWS::S3::S3Object.store("image.png", thumb.to_blob, AWS_BUCKET, :content_type => 'image/png', :access => :public_read)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: They must have changed the API back: as of rmagick 4.2.2, `thumb.format = ...` works again, and `thumb.format(...)` no longer works.  Still this looks like a useful answer for those using some older version of rmagick."