# Saving a GIF image with RMagick failure

Tags: ruby, rmagick

I'm using ruby 2.1.0, rmagick 2.15.4, ImageMagick 6.7.7-10

I'd like to load a JPEG file and then save in the GIF format.

```
x = Magick::Image.read("a.jpg").first
puts "Start write..."
x.format = "GIF"
x.write("a.gif")
puts "Done."
```

Gives me this:

```
Start write...
cli.rb:104:in `exit': no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
```

The stack trace includes foreman and thor gems, but no step in my code.

The filesystem has a.gif defined, but the filesize is zero.

**UPDATE**
I think I have a problem with ImageMagick itself.  Here's what happens on the command line:

```
$ convert -debug a.jpg a.gif
convert.im6: unrecognized event type `a.jpg' @error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1135.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this question was answered here:

[JPG to PNG using RMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6419388/jpg-to-png-using-rmagick)

Just changing the file name will not convert he file format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. Something else is going on here.

"This makes it easy to convert an image file to another format. Simply write the image file using a name that has either a prefix or a suffix corresponding to the format you want."

https://rmagick.github.io/imusage.html